# Get subtype of Generic List in Dart

Tags: dart

How can I get the subtype of a List which is a generic type in Dart?
For example:

```
T is List< String > => String

T is List< SomeObject > => SomeObject
```

I have researched for this questions but I just found some workarounds.
Any suggestions on this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to get the actual type argument of a list as a type at run-time.
Dart has no way to deconstruct the type `List<X>` to get to `X` if the class itself does not provide one.

If `dart:mirrors` is available, you might be able to use it to find the type as a `Type` object, which should be sufficient for this case, but mirrors are not available in Flutter.

Answer (score 6):

To provide a more recent update for anyone still searching this:

From Dart 2.7 you can use an Extension Method to achieve this:

```
// extensions/list.dart

extension Typing<T> on List<T> {
    /// Provide access to the generic type at runtime.
    Type get genericType => T;
}
```

https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods#implementing-generic-extensions

You then use it by importing it and using it like any other `List` function:

```
import './extensions/list.dart';

List<String> myList = ['some', 'strings'];

print('Your List type is ${myList.genericType}!');
```

This works with the caveat that it returns the declared type `T` so if this is a superclass of the type at runtime, you still only get whatever type the `List` was declared with in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function to get the type parameter of a List:

```
Type typeOfElementsInList<T>(List<T> e) => T;
main() {
  print(typeOfElementsInList([]));        // dynamic
  print(typeOfElementsInList(<int>[]));   // int
  print(typeOfElementsInList(['test']));  // String
}
```

Comment: This only gets the type argument of the *static* type of the expression. If you have `List<Object> o = <int>[1];print(typeOfElementsInList(o));` it will print `Object`, not `int`.

Comment: Yes. The question wasn't really clear about what was wanted.